# Es correcto ese constructor que me pide el ejercicio?

Tags: java

Esa es la pregunta:
Los constructores que se implementarán serán
1.Un constructor por defecto.
2.Un constructor con el color y el precio.
3.Un constructor con todos los atributos.

Y puse mi código

```
public class Muebles {
    String tipoMadera, color;
    double precioBase;
    // Metodo construsctor por defecto
    public Muebles() {
        tipoMadera="pino"+"caoba"+"roble"+"teca";
        color="original";
    }
    // Constructor con color , precio
    public Muebles(String color, double precioBase) {
        this.color = color;
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
    }
    // constructor con todos los atributos.Aqui hay mas atributos por herencia 
    public Muebles(String tipoMadera, String color, double precioBase) {
        this.tipoMadera = tipoMadera;
        this.color = color;
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: La mayor prioridad es el método constructor por defecto eso quiero saber si esta bien?

Comment: No estás fijando precio base por defecto.

Comment: Cierto me falto poner, pero esta bien el constructor por defecto?

Comment: No es una cuestión de prioridad. Veamos algunos ejemplos: `$m=new Muebles();` ahí se usa el constructor que no tiene parámetros, en ese caso `precioBase` será `NULL` por lo que te dijo @Alfabravo . `$m=new Muebles("azul",10.02);` ahí se usa el segundo constructor. `$m=new Muebles("pino", "verde",99.99);` ahí se usa el tercer constructor. No hay mayor misterio. Una cosa, la clase debería llamarse `Mueble`, no `Muebles` en plural. No es que sea erróneo, pero es más coherente con la *convención de nombre*. La clase crea una instancia (tipo) de mueble, no varios muebles.

Comment: @LenninJesús lo correcto es definir el constructor por defecto vacío y sin parámetros, también puedes no escribirlo ya que " El compilador proporciona automáticamente un constructor predeterminado sin argumentos para cualquier clase sin constructores."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Un constructor por defecto.

El constructor por defecto es un constructor sin parámetros que no hace nada, por lo cual puedes definirlo vacío.

**Es importante saber que este constructor puedes definirlo aunque no es necesario escribirlo**.

**Si para una clase no se define ningún método constructor, el compilador proporciona automáticamente un constructor predeterminado sin argumentos para cualquier clase sin constructores.**

```
 public Muebles() {  
 }
```

Revisa la documentación oficial:

[Proporcionando constructores para sus clases Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) (inglés)

2.Un constructor con el color y el precio.

```
 public Muebles(String color, double precioBase) {
    this.color = color;
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
 }
```

3.Un constructor con todos los atributos.

```
 //constructor con todos los atributos.Aqui hay mas atributos por herencia 
 public Muebles(String tipoMadera, String color, double precioBase) {
    this.tipoMadera = tipoMadera;
    this.color = color;
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
 }
```

---

Este sería el código, incluso el método del punto dos puede en realidad llamar al constructor que recibe la mayor cantidad de parámetros.

```
public class Muebles {
 String tipoMadera, color;
 double precioBase;

 //Metodo contrusctor por defecto
 public Muebles() {
 }

 //Constructor con color , precio
 public Muebles(String color, double precioBase) {
   Muebles("", color, precioBase)
 }

 public Muebles(String tipoMadera, String color, double precioBase) {
    this.tipoMadera = tipoMadera;
    this.color = color;
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
 }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su sencilla respuesta

Comment: Me da gusto fue de ayuda saludos @LenninJesús

Answer (score 0):

lo común es tener un constructor por defecto y otro por parámetro que cubra todos los atributos de la clase.No se por que te piden esos 3.En el constructor por defecto te falta el precio base.

Además recuerda ponerle visibilidad a los atributos, deberían ser privados.

```
public class Muebles {
 private String tipoMadera, color;
 private double precioBase;
```

Si no tiene clases hijas ponlos privados, si tiene clases hijas a tu criterio decidís si ponerle los atributos protected o privados.